# In VBA why is comparing two doubles quicker than comparing two long

Tags: vba, compare, double, long-integer

I am trying to optimize the speed of my code.  My original code was comparing two prices so I was using double.  But then I thought maybe changing them to long may speed up the process.  But the time to compare two double seems to be almost half that of comparing two longs.  Why is this?

run the variables m,n,p as long or double

```
Sub FastTest()
Dim x, y, z As Integer
Dim m, n, p As Double
'Dim m, n, p As Long
Dim StartTime As Double

StartTime = Timer()

'm = CLng(115658573)
'n = CLng(45357896)

m = 115658573
n = 45357896

For x = 1 To 1000
    For y = 1 To 1000
        For z = 1 To 100
            If m > n Then
                p = m + n
            End If
        Next
    Next
Next

MsgBox Timer - StartTime
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Every VBA programmer falls into this trap. In this declaration

```
Dim x, y, z As Integer
Dim m, n, p As Double
```

x, y, m, n are declared as `Variant`, and then VBA will decide the type in run-time. Declare the variables this way

```
Dim x As Long, y As Long, z As Long
Dim m As Double, n As Double, p As Double
```

and run the test again and let me know the result :)

+1: declare integers as `Long`. You could think you can save memory with using only 2 bytes for an integer, but it is a compatibility feature and VBA will convert them to long in run-time anyway.

Comment: +1 for the `Integer` anecdote. Keep in mind though that some old API calls require 16 bit integer input, which is where one has to declare the variable as an `Integer` in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make clear and correct test.

```
Dim m, n, p As Double
Debug.Print "m:=" & VarType(m) & " n:=" & VarType(n) & " p:=" & VarType(p)
```

return: `m:=0 n:=0 p:=5`

```
Dim m, n, p As Double
m = 115658573
n = 45357896
p = m + n
Debug.Print "m:=" & VarType(m) & " n:=" & VarType(n) & " p:=" & VarType(p)
```

return: `m:=3 n:=3 p:=5`

```
Dim m As Double
Dim n As Double
Dim p As Double
Debug.Print "m:=" & VarType(m) & " n:=" & VarType(n) & " p:=" & VarType(p)
```

return: `m:=5 n:=5 p:=5`

Look to [VarType function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function) for more information about returned values.

Comment: You are always checking the `VarType` of `m` which is why your return values are the same, when in fact they should only be so in the last test.

Comment: @Nacorid As I see, after initialization variable get "right" type. That's why I show 3 examples.

Comment: But you are checking 3 times for the `VarType` of `m` per example, when you should check each variable per example

Comment: o! sorry, copy/paste )))